# Customizing x-axis of graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `scale_x_discrete()` to customize ticks and labels of x-axis.

However, as figure shows, the lines cut the right-side y-axis, which doesn't look good to me. Could you please help me to fix this. The data (temp) is also shown below.

```
> a = ggplot(data = temp, aes(b, c, group=a,shape=a,colour=a), ordered=TRUE) + geom_line() + geom_point() 
> a
> b = a + scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("2","4","8","16","32","64","128"), labels=c("2","4","8","16","32","64","128"))

> temp
       a   b    c
1    One   2  5.1
2    One   4  6.6
3    One   8  7.7
4    One  16  8.4
5    One  32 16.1
6    One  64 38.0
7    One 128 49.2
8    Two   2  5.9
9    Two   4  7.7
10   Two   8  9.2
11   Two  16 10.3
12   Two  32 16.8
13   Two  64 32.4
14   Two 128 45.7
15 Three   2  4.7
16 Three   4  7.0
17 Three   8  8.5
18 Three  16  9.6
19 Three  32 14.8
20 Three  64 31.0
21 Three 128 34.5
22  Four   2  4.3
23  Four   4  6.9
24  Four   8  8.3
25  Four  16  9.1
26  Four  32 14.0
27  Four  64 23.8
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why are you using a discrete scale for something at appears to be continuous.

If you replace `scale_x_discrete` with `scale_x_continuous` then this should work as you wish.

```
b <- a + scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2^(1:7))
b
```

[image]
You might be interested in a transformation to base 2, given the way your data for `b` appear only to be integer powers of 2.

```
a + scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2^(1:7), trans = 'log2')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is also the "expand" argument from the ggplot website. Adjust the numbers to whatever look you are trying to achieve

```
a + scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("2","4","8","16","32","64","128"),
                     labels=c("2","4","8","16","32","64","128"),
                     expand = c(.1,.1))
```