# Customize x-axis ticks with scale_x_discrete and scale_x_continuous

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wanted to have my ticks on x-axis looking like this(but no dash needed)

3(12)  -  5(20)   -   7(28)  -  9(36)   -   11(44)   -   13(52)

The original graph is

[image]

made with

```html
  n.clusters mean.cluster mean.bucket   variable    value
1           3     21.64790    21.49858 sd.cluster 5.643380
2           5     21.63516    21.54975 sd.cluster 4.369756
3           7     21.55446    21.49889 sd.cluster 3.643280
4           9     21.59585    21.57022 sd.cluster 3.237870
5          11     21.63110    21.58452 sd.cluster 3.012060
6          13     21.55224    21.56104 sd.cluster 2.643777
7           3     21.64790    21.49858  sd.bucket 5.648886
8           5     21.63516    21.54975  sd.bucket 4.397690
9           7     21.55446    21.49889  sd.bucket 3.654752
10          9     21.59585    21.57022  sd.bucket 3.262954
11         11     21.63110    21.58452  sd.bucket 3.023834
12         13     21.55224    21.56104  sd.bucket 2.716441
```

```html
ggplot(data, aes(n.clusters, value, shape=variable, group=variable)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_point(size = 3.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 13, 2)) +
  scale_shape_discrete(solid=F,
                       name = "Variable",
                       breaks = c("sd.cluster", "sd.bucket"),
                       labels = c("sd.cluster", "sd.bucket")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=16),
        axis.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold")) +
  labs(x = "Number of cluster",
       y = "Value")
```

As referred to these links, I made some changes in the code
 https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/501

[Customizing x-axis of graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850329/customizing-x-axis-of-ggplot-graph)

and got these at best but not resulted what I wanted.

```html
ggplot(data = mu.est.summary.long, aes(n.clusters, value, shape=variable, group=variable)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_point(size = 3.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("3","5","7","9","11","13"),
                   labels = c("3(12)", "5(20)", "7(28)", "9(36)", "11(44)", "13(52)") +
  scale_shape_discrete(solid=F,
                       name = "Variable",
                       breaks = c("sd.cluster", "sd.bucket"),
                       labels = c("sd.cluster", "sd.bucket")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=16),
        axis.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold")) +
  labs(x = "Number of cluster",
       y = "Value")
```

Within `scale_x_discrete`:
Using neither `limits=c(levels(n.clusters$data)` nor `breaks=c()` nor `breaks= seq()` didn't work. R keeps saying that something is missing... What did I miss?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what do you mean by "and got these at best but not resulted what I wanted."?  I ran your code and I see the labels you want, so what's wrong...I don't have any warning message like you suggest ("R keeps saying that something is missing")

Comment: I wanted the ticks to say 3(12)  -  5(20) ... and so on as described in the beginning of the post. "R keeps saying that something is missing" means no graph was produced and R was prompting for more command (with `+` after the last line of the code.

Comment: it just means there is a typo in your code...a ")" is missing after ""13(52)")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using `scale_x_discrete`, make sure the variable for the x axis is not continuous.  If you are labeling the x-axis with numbers, R will read them in as continuous and you need to specify `as.factor(df$name)` to work with a discrete axis.